# Recording the id of a discord message when it is sent with a bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a program that sends out messages on a discord server. I'd like to add a method for getting the message that has just been sent, so i can print its message_id

```
@bot.command(name='repeat', help='help me to understand bots')
async def repeat(ctx, *lines):
    await asyncio.gather(*[ctx.send(line) for line in lines])
    print("message_id")
```

We could do this with the fetch command but that seems inelegant. Intuitively it seems like there should be a method of getting details like method_id from the send function but i can't find anything like that in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Messageable.send` returns a `discord.Message` instance, you can use the `id` attribute to get it's ID.

Also the `asyncio.gather` function is not really necessary here, I would just use a normal for loop and append the ID's to a list

```py
@bot.command(name='repeat', help='help me to understand bots')
async def repeat(ctx, *lines):
    message_ids = []

    for line in lines:
        m = await ctx.send(line)
        message_ids.append(m.id)

    print(message_ids)
```

If you really want to stick with `asyncio.gather`

```py
@bot.command(name='repeat', help='help me to understand bots')
async def repeat(ctx, *lines):
    message_ids = []

    async def send_line(line):
        m = await ctx.send(line)
        message_ids.append(m.id) 

    await asyncio.gather(*[send_line(line) for line in lines])
    print(message_ids)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Messageable.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send)
- [`Message.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.id)